# I'm trying to use previous movement scripts for unity but get the same error? (For unity 2d)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

As the title says: I'm working on a project and no matter what I do when EDIT-> Thank you so much, I forgot that you can't have it outside the class

I use 'Rigidbody2D' and I get this error

> CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

for the 3 variables before the class

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public float movementSpeed = 1f;
public Vector2 movement;
private Rigidbody2D rb;

public class movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        movement.x = Imput.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    }

    void FixedUpdate(){
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * movementSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, move the fields into the class. Fields (etc) cannot exist outside a class, as the compiler is telling you in the error.

Comment: Thank you, but now its saying the vector2 "member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type"

Answer (score 0):

"So, move the fields into the class. Fields (etc) cannot exist outside a class, as the compiler is telling you in the error" Thank you stuartd